# NameError in Ckeditor::PicturesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I use ckeditor with mongoid & carrierwave in my rails 3.2.6 app. All installed like here https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor
All works fine, but when i try upload file or picture, i have error:

NameError in Ckeditor::PicturesController#create

uninitialized constant Assetable

Parameters:

```
{"upload"=># @content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
@tempfile=#>,
"CKEditor"=>"content_page_version_partial_content",
"CKEditorFuncNum"=>"2",
"langCode"=>"en",
"authenticity_token"=>"4dpd7COrvkSq+I6sCcPmGHlP5hr++Q9TWQtStZNqWSg="}
```

Whats wrong? How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to initialize carrierwave and activeadmin?
use rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave